# In vscode extension, is there a way to watch file changes in node_modules without change files.watcherExclude?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a vscode extension, and I want to watch specific file changes in `node_modules` according to the extensions's configuration, but I don't want user to change their default `files.watcherExclude`. What should I do?

For example, considering vscode's native typescript language feature, when I change a `.d.ts` file in `node_modules`, the ts-server can detect that and provide the latest intellisense. How does ts-server watch file changes in `node_modules`?

Comment: It sounds like you can watch specific files non-recursively yes? From ` workspace.createFileSystemWatche()`: "If you need to watch in a location that is typically excluded (for example node_modules or .git folder), then you can use a non-recursive watcher in the workspace for this purpose."

Comment: I tried `workspace.createFileSystemWatcher("/Users/myname/proj/node_modules/mod/index.css")`, but it still does not work. Nothing happens after changing `index.css`